# Identification of a sot363 dual transistor

Tags: transistors, identification, pnp, dual

Could you please help me in the identification of the 6 pins dual PNP transistors below. 
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Googling "smd marking code MA" led me here:

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MBT3904DW1T1-D.PDF

However, it's not a dual PNP. It's dual NPN instead.